# How do I send whole object to Firebase database?

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

How I could send in correct way object with his own properties to the data base ?

Let's say object with properties :

```
class Test {
 var name:String
 var age:Int

 init(name: String, age: Int) {
  self.name = name
  self.age = age
 }
}

(...)
let obj = Test(name: "Jack", age: 25)
let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Person")

databaseRef.setValue(obj)
```

Data base should looks like this :

[image]

Whenever I add new person I'll get new child as a "person" parent.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For that, first you need to generate the unique `personId` using `childByAutoId()` and then add the person details to it.

```
let newPersonRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Person").childByAutoId()
let obj = Test(name: "Jack", age: 25)
newPersonRef.setValue(obj.toDictionary())
```

If you also want that newly created person's unique reference id:

```
let newPersonRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Person").childByAutoId()
print(newPersonRef.key)
```

**Edit:** Add one function with return type `Any` inside your `Test` class.

```
func toDictionary() -> Any {
    return ["name":name, "age": age] as Any
}
```

And then set the test object in Firebase this way:

```
let obj = Test(name: "Jack", age: 25)
newPersonRef.setValue(obj.toDictionary())
```

Comment: is it going to be a same way with sending [Test]() into the data base ? That i have to use "for each" loop ?

Comment: @DerpyUnKnown You need to use for loop for that because you want to set unique person id

Comment: Btw. 'InvalidFIrebaseData', reasons : setValue can not store object or type Test. Can only store objects of type NSNUmber, NSString, NSDictionary and NSArray

Comment: @DerpyUnKnown I thought you are passing dictionary this for just showing. Let me edit the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much ! Syntax of Swift is totally new for me.

Comment: @DerpyUnKnown Welcome mate, It happens some time :)